# Why the output of the following code is 7.00649e-45?

Tags: c++, pointers

Is it a garbage value?
Even in garbage values I have never seen exponents before.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    short s=5;
    float f= * (float*)&s;
    cout<< f << endl;

}
```

Edit:Now I understood that it's one of those few cases where you must know Computer architecture i.e. what's actually happening at memory level.

Comment: Why would you expect `5.0`? `float` and `short` aren't even the same size.

Comment: It's trying to interpret the bits in `s`, along with some of the surrounding stack contents, as a `float`. There is no reason for that to result in *anything* sensible, or even predictable.

Comment: Sorry,I wasn't expecting exactly 5.0 actually I was thinking of something with zeros after a decimal.

Comment: There's no particular reason you should have any particular expectations about what output this code will produce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code coerces an integer value into a floating point value by moving the raw bit representation into a float; this happens because you cast the *pointer* from `short*` to `float*` -- this does not in any way cast the underlying *value* being pointed to. Floating point representation is not compatible with integer representation, so basically, yes, you are getting a garbage value.

Additionally, on typical x86/x86_64 machines short is 2 bytes, while float is 4 bytes, so the number being read out as a floating point value is not just the contents of the short value you added, but also the stack space immediately after it in memory.

### More Detail (about floating point representation)

I am assuming you are using a little-endian machine, e.g. x86/x86_64.

A short value is two bytes. In little-endian encoding, the lower byte comes first, so the decimal value `5` looks like this in memory:

```
05 00
```

A floating point value is four bytes. So when the system tries to load your two bytes as a float, it also has to look at the next two bytes. If your stack ha not yet reached this far down, then the next two bytes are probably zero, so this is what our floating point number looks like, as a raw hex value in memory:

```
05 00 00 00
```

However, since your system is little-endian, when you actually want to interpret this value, the way it is read in order is like this:

```
00 00 00 05
```

So this is the raw binary representation of the floating point value. But what value do these bits represent? For this we have to know how they are interpreted. This will be according to the IEEE 754 standard for single-precision floating point numbers, which you can read more about [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

The summary of this interpretation is here:

[image]

So if you interpret the given bit string according to the rules for interpreting floating point numbers, the resulting value is 7.006492321624085e-45, exactly the answer you got.

An easy way to see this is with python's "struct" module:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('<f', b'\x05\x00\x00\x00')
(7.006492321624085e-45,)
```

`<` means interpret the following bytes as little endian, `f` means interpret the following bytes as a float.

Note that if you were on a big-endian machine, the short representation would be `00 05 00 00`, but the float representation would then be `00 05 00 00`. Again we can find out what value this represents by interpreting the bit pattern using python's struct module:

```
>>> struct.unpack('>f', b'\x00\x05\x00\x00')
(4.5917748078995606e-40,)
```

(`>` means that we are interpreting it as big-endian this time)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but if it is a garbage value then it should give me different values on different compilers,I checked it even with some online compilers it is giving me the same value everywhere.

Comment: Garbage value does not mean random value. If the stack space following the short is set to zero (which it is likely to be if the program has just started), and the short always has the same value, then the bit pattern being copied into the float will always be the same bit pattern. This will always result in the *same* garbage pattern, but it is garbage nonetheless.

Comment: Garbage values are so unpredictable that they're sometimes predictable!

Answer (score 2):

Likely your platform happened to allocate four bytes and filled them with zeroes except for the 5. The 5 was interpreted as the least significant binary digits. 5/(2^149) is 7.00649232e-45.

Answer (score 0):

You want `float f = (float)s`, since you expected to get 5.0, or if you really want to reinterpret the bits (which might make sense with a `uint32_t` and a `float`, which are the same size), `reinterpret_cast`. The C-style way of doing this kind of type-punning would be to make a union with a member of each type, store to it using one type, and read from it using the other type.

What you did isn’t legal, and on some systems, it would crash the program with a bus error because, on that CPU, the types have different memory-alignment requirements.